# How to properly rotate a Pawn (Player Possessed) in Unreal Engine?

Tags: c++, unreal-4, unreal

[image]

```
// called from 'Tick'
void APlayerPawn::DoRotation(float dt)
{
    float mousex = -InputComponent->GetAxisValue(TEXT("MOUSEX"));
    float mousey = InputComponent->GetAxisValue(TEXT("MOUSEY"));

    //AddControllerYawInput(mousex * TURN_SPEED * dt);
    AddControllerYawInput(100 * dt);

    FRotator camera_rot = camera->GetRelativeRotation();
    camera_rot.Pitch += mousey * LOOK_SPEED * dt;
    camera_rot.Pitch = FMath::Clamp(camera_rot.Pitch, -MAX_LOOK_PITCH, MAX_LOOK_PITCH);
    camera->SetRelativeRotation(camera_rot.Quaternion());


}
```

I have a strange problem with my Pawn class. I am simply trying to rotate the root object (in this instance, 'mesh') using mouse movement.

I have this function, and I have tried many variations of the same thing. This one is using `AddControllerYawInput` from the APawn class. But I have also written it using `FQuat` quaternions, and also `FRotator` values. I must have tried at least 5 different approaches that all ended up with the same result (as shown in the GIF clip).

As you can see, I have hardcoded a value instead of using mouse input. I expect the rotation to be pretty much a constant speed. Instead it seems to be on a curve, it gets faster until a point then slows down to zero for a moment and repeats.

I am sure I used this code before in a previous project but unfortunately I lost access to all my old projects so this is all I have.

Edit:
For example if I rewrite it like so, the result is the same:

```
void APlayerPawn::DoRotation(float dt)
{
    float mousex = -InputComponent->GetAxisValue(TEXT("MOUSEX"));
    float mousey = InputComponent->GetAxisValue(TEXT("MOUSEY"));

    //AddControllerYawInput(mousex * TURN_SPEED * dt);
    //AddControllerYawInput(100 * dt);

    //currentYaw += 100 * dt;
    //FRotator player_rot = mesh->GetRelativeRotation();
    //player_rot.Yaw = currentYaw;
    //mesh->SetRelativeRotation(player_rot); <-result=same as GIF

    currentYaw += 100 * dt;
    FQuat player_quat = mesh->GetRelativeTransform().GetRotation();
    FRotator player_rot = player_quat.Rotator();
    player_rot.Yaw = currentYaw;
    //mesh->SetRelativeTransform(player_rot.Quaternion()); //result=same again
    SetActorRotation(player_rot.Quaternion()); //result= same as in gif video

    FRotator camera_rot = camera->GetRelativeRotation();
    camera_rot.Pitch += mousey * LOOK_SPEED * dt;
    camera_rot.Pitch = FMath::Clamp(camera_rot.Pitch, -MAX_LOOK_PITCH, MAX_LOOK_PITCH);
    camera->SetRelativeRotation(camera_rot.Quaternion());
}
```